# OpenCL GPU Audio

Tags: audio, opencl, real-time

There's not much on this subject, perhaps because it isn't a good idea in the first place.

I want to create a realtime audio synthesis/processing engine that runs on the GPU.  The reason for this is because I will also be using a physics library that runs on the GPU, and the audio output will be determined by the physics state.  Is it true that GPU only carries audio output and can't generate it?  Would this mean a large increase in latency, if I were to read the data back on the CPU and output it to the soundcard?  I'm looking for a latency between 10 and 20ms in terms of the time between synthesis and playback.

Would the GPU accelerate synthesis by any worthwhile amount?  I'm going to have a large number of synthesizers running at once, each of which I imagine could take up their own parallel process.  AMD is coming out with GPU audio, so there must be something to this.

Comment: Research paper on GPU synthesis: http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2484010

Comment: I have achieved this with OpenCL and Java and it is performant enough for realtime on my Apple M1 GPU. https://bitbucket.org/almostrealism/replicator/src/develop/audio/src/main/java/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DSP operations on modern CPUs with vector processing units (SSE on x86/x64 or NEON on ARM) are already pretty cheap if exploited properly.  This is particularly the case with filters, convolution, FFT and so on - which are fundamentally stream-based operations.   There are the type of operations where a GPU might also excel.

As it turns out, soft synthesisers have quite a few operations in them that are not stream-like, and furthermore, the tendency is to process increasingly small chunks of audio at once to target low latency.  These are a really bad fit for the capabilities of GPU.

The effort involved in using a GPU - particularly getting data in and out - is likely to far exceed any benefit you get.  Furthermore, the capabilities of inexpensive personal computers - and also tablets and mobile devices - are more than enough for many digital audio applications  AMD seem to have a solution looking for a problem.   For sure, the existing music and digital audio software industry is not about to start producing software that only targets a limited sub-set of hardware.

Answer (score 13):

For what it's worth, I'm not sure that this idea lacks merit. If DarkZero's observation about transfer times is correct, it doesn't sound like there would be much overhead in getting audio onto the GPU for processing, even from many different input channels, and while there are probably audio operations that are not very amenable to parallelization, many are very VERY parallelizable.

It's obvious for example, that computing sine values for 128 samples of output from a sine source could be done completely in parallel. Working in blocks of that size would permit a latency of only about 3ms, which is acceptable in most digital audio applications. Similarly, the many other fundamental oscillators could be effectively parallelized. Amplitude modulation of such oscillators would be trivial. Efficient frequency modulation would be more challenging, but I would guess it is still possible.

In addition to oscillators, FIR filters are simple to parallelize, and a google search turned up some promising looking research papers (which I didn't take the trouble to read) that suggest that there are reasonable parallel approaches to IIR filter implementation. These two types of filters are fundamental to audio processing and many useful audio operations can be understood as such filters.

Wave-shaping is another task in digital audio that is embarrassingly parallel.

Even if you couldn't take an arbitrary software synth and map it effectively to the GPU, it is easy to imagine a software synthesizer constructed specifically to take advantage of the GPU's strengths, and avoid its weaknesses. A synthesizer relying exclusively on the components I have mentioned could still produce a fantastic range of sounds.

While marko is correct to point out that existing SIMD instructions can do some parallelization on the CPU, the number of inputs they can operate on at the same time pales in comparison to a good GPU.

In short, I hope you work on this and let us know what kind of results you see!

Comment: Some other possibilities: (1) if you want to create an ensemble effect by making a thousand copies of the same synthesiser, that would obviously parallelise; (2) waveguide-based reverbs and physical modelling would parallelise really well if you have a big network.

Answer (score 4):

Typical transfer times for some MB to/from GPU take 50us.

Delay is not your problem, however parallelizing a audio synthesizer in the GPU may be quite difficult. If you don't do it properly it may take more time the processing rather than the copy of data.

If you are going to run multiple synthetizers at once, I would recommend you to perform each synthesizer in a work-group, and parallelize the synthesis process with the work-items available. It will not be worth to have each synthesizer in one work-item, since it is unlikely you will have thousand.

Answer (score 1):

http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1211/1211.2038.pdf
You might be better off using OpenMP for it's lower initialization times.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the [NESS project](http://www.ness.music.ed.ac.uk/project#4) which is all about physical modelling synthesis. They are using GPUs for audio rendering because it the process involves simulating an acoustic 3D space for whichever given sound, and calculating what happens to that sound within the virtual 3D space (and apparently GPUs are good at working with this sort of data). Note that this is not realtime synthesis because it is so demanding of processing.

Comment: In one of their videos they said that some of it was realtime, but I imagine that was on a pretty beefy compute server.